# Vba Listobject Auto Filter unique items

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am an excel newbie and for a project, I am trying to create a userform through which the user will make a series of selections to get the result.

For example, I have a table like the following.

```
Type  | Color   | Item
---------------------
Fruit | Yellow | Mango 
Fruit | Red    | Apple
Veggie| Green  | Broccoli
```

I want the user to select from combo box, first the type and then the color to determine the item.

I am using list object filter to populate the combo box. I am able make a selection, for example Fruit from combo box 1. And Yellow from cobo box 2 to get Mango as the result. But, the problem I am running into is that my combo box has duplicate entires.

My questions are:
1. Is there a way through the tables, I will be able to just get the unique items to populate the combo box. Or, 
2. Is there a neat little trick to get rid of the duplicates in the combo box?

Comment: There are many many ways to populate a combobox with unique items. The most simplest is to create a unique `Collection` and then add that to the combobox... Give it a try and if you get stuck then simply post the code that you tried and we will take it from there :)

Comment: Another method is to use the Advanced Filter function to extract a list of unique items which can then be added to the combobox. This link should get you started http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html